# Typescript different interface depending on function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

I have following scenario, i have 2 interfaces:

```
export interface UserInterface extends Document {
    email: string,
    role: string,
    created: Date,
    disabled: Boolean,
    author: AuthorInterface
}

export interface UserModelInterface extends UserInterface {
    password: string
}
```

and i have one method:

```
public findUserById(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, sensitive: Boolean = false): Promise<UserInterface | null> {
    if (sensitive) return User.findOne({ _id }).exec()
    return User.findOne({ _id }, { password: 0 }).exec()
}
```

I want following:

This is an method that gets an user by ID.
`sensitive` is by default at `false` witch leads that the password is exluded so i use `UserInterface`

Problem i have now is if somebody sets sensitive on `true` then i would need to use `UserModelInterface` and not `UserInterface`  because password is excluded in `UserInterface`

Is this possible?

Comment: That's what overloading is good for.

Comment: @Bergi could you explain it? or link me some ressources?

Comment: first hit: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bergi for showing me the direction. The solution is to use overloads:

```
public findUserById(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, sensitive?: false): Promise<UserInterface | null>
public findUserById(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, sensitive?: true): Promise<UserModelInterface | null>

public findUserById(_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string, sensitive: Boolean = false): Promise<UserModelInterface | UserInterface | null> {
    if (sensitive) return User.findOne({ _id }).exec()
    return User.findOne({ _id }, { password: 0 }).exec()
}
```